# Code::Blocks cannot find vector header

Tags: c++, linux, vector, codeblocks

EDIT: I have solved this problem, with Tomalak's help. It appears that I mistakenly uninstalled libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3 when I was making space to install code::blocks into, thus removing the STL headers. Code::Blocks now works perfectly fine.

Hey everyone, I'm back yet again to bug you.

I have recently installed Code::Blocks in order to follow along with a SDL tutorial, mainly to make it easier with the file creation process (i.e. not having to deal with makefiles for the time being)

I have been compiling/running the examples (so far) just fine, but I've now hit a snag.

On the tutorial for entities, the header file includes <vector> - yet code::blocks is stating it cannot find said header file. It's a .h header file, but it's recognizing it as C++ (I think, judging from the project options) - all my headers are .h, all my sources are .cpp...

I have searched Google for a solution, and many people state that this error occurs when they try to use  in a .c file by mistake. This is not the case, unless Code::Blocks is recognizing my .h as a C-header.

In case you're wondering, I am running Lucid Puppy Linux 5.2 (aka LuPu), a Ubuntu derivative. (Installed Code::Blocks from the Ubuntu repositories)

In advance, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Did you include other standard header files yet? Maybe Code::Blocks just doesn't know your stdlib path, who knows.

Comment: No, I have not. I'll try that. EDIT: Cannot find iostream, either.

Comment: The extension of your header should not matter, as long as you are using it conventionally; that is, `#include`ing it into a C++ source file, rather than trying to compile it independently.

Comment: @Tomalak, that is what I am doing.

Comment: @FurryHead: I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks, but if you have to "create a project" to put your files in, did you make sure it's a "C++ project", if it asks?

Comment: @FurryHead: Is Code::Blocks compiling your code as C (gcc) or c++ (g++)?

Comment: Then you need to point Code::Blocks to your stdlib path, unfortunately I don't use Linux, so I don't know where exactly that is. :(

Comment: @tomalak It does not ask - supposedly it determines that based on whether the files are .c/.cpp/.cxx, which I am using .cpp

Comment: @Erik, I don't know how to determine that - the project properties show that the compiler variable to be used is CPP, however.

Comment: @Xeo, what would the stdlib path be? include or lib? Guessing include?

Comment: Yes, include path for your C++ standard library. Normally the IDE should be able to figure it out itself, but seems it didn't for you.

Comment: @FurryHead: OK, sounds fine so far. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @Tomalak, not a problem. I'm currently trying to figure out where the standard c++ headers are on my system, as that seems to be the problem. if anyone knows where they are on a ubuntu derived system...

Comment: @FurryHead: Often `/usr/local/include/` or somesuch. Why not type `find / -name vector` into your terminal?

Comment: @Tomalak: ROFL, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I've used find enough times now I should have... FYI, it's at /usr/include/c++/4.4/ - testing now.

Comment: @FurryHead: Code::Blocks would have set that up itself, so I would have been surprised if manually adding the include path helped. Out of interest, what _is_ in the IDE's include path settings?

Comment: @Tomalak, the include field is empty.

Comment: @FurryHead: Can you re-install Code::Blocks?

Comment: @Tomalak, I suppose I could, but at the moment my internet is cutting out randomly so not right now. I doubt it'd fix it, though.

Comment: Wow. Just made a testproj, with the most basic code I could think of: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}
`    /root/learncpp/testing/main.cpp|1|error: iostream: No such file or directory|

Comment: @FurryHead: I think it probably would.

Comment: Alright, @Tomalak. I'll uninstall the code::blocks package and re-install it. Be back as soon as it reinstalls, and I test it.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: @Tomalak, I don't have apt/apt-get - Puppy linux has it's own package manager (solely gui-based, PITA!) and I must use that to do any package management. (It has access to the ubuntu repos, not the ubuntu package manager)

Comment: @Tomalak also I don't think it's a build problem; it must be code::blocks as gcc/g++ work fine using iostream/vector

Comment: @Tomalak, successfully re-installed code::blocks, same problem.

Comment: @FurryHead: You wouldn't usually pass the stdlib include path manually to `g++`, so that's odd. Can you _confirm_ that `g++`, not `gcc`, is being invoked?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, according to the options g++ is the default compiler for C++ - I will check the Makefile, though

Comment: @Tomalak, cannot find the Makefile. I don't see anywhere else that says gcc/g++ compiler.

Comment: Oh dear. I just tried compiling one of my previous applications as I do normally, and suddenly it also cannot find iostream! AHH! It appears it is now a g++ problem, and not soleley code::blocks

Comment: @FurryHead: Turn on full Compiler logging. This is done by selecting the "Full command line" option Under menu "Settings" -> "Compiler and Debugger" -> Global compiler settings -> [the compiler you use] -> "Other Setting" tab, "Compiler logging". This option will make Code::Blocks output the exact commands it uses to compile your code.  (This came from [the FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ).)

Comment: @Tomalak It outputs `g++ -Wall -02 <file> <outfile>` - I have to get off anyway, I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @FurryHead: Verbatim? Doesn't it show the actual filenames? And surely there's "-o" before `<outfile>`? And executing this exact command from a terminal is successful? If not, what differences are there?

Comment: @Tomalak, it's not verbatim - and I missed the -o switch. I just didn't feel like typing the huge long pathnames. And no, it's no longer successful - I just discovered that g++ is n longer working on previously working projects. Apparently, it's now a gcc/g++ problem.

Comment: @Tomalak, I am so sorry for putting you through all this. It appears that I mistakenly uninstalled libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3 package when I was freeing up disk space to install code::blocks. Man, I hate the Puppy Package Manager.

Comment: @FurryHead: Wow, just wow. xD

Comment: @Furry if you've solved your question, answer it yourself and accept it in two days. Or let @Tomalak answer it so he can get the rep.

Comment: @FurryHead: That's quite... special. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @Tomalak, if you'll post an answer I'll gladly give you the rep. You've been put through enough to earn it... haha.

Comment: @FurryHead: It's your solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, alright then. More rep for me LOL ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was not a Code::Blocks issue - I had mistakenly un-installed the libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3 package.

So, if any of you all get this same problem make sure the libstdc++ development files are installed! LOL